# Multiple labels per feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

Is it possible to display a label multiple times in QGIS?

[image]

For example, displaying the label several times along the red line in the above image? A copy and paste function would do the job.

Answer (score 9):

In labeling in the Placement tab there is the option to repeat the label along the line....

[image]

Comment: you where faster :( take my vote!

Comment: indeed, mine too ;-)